How to fix error when using Supabase CLI while pushing to remote DB?
I am using the Supabase CLI to develop locally. I did some changes to my local db, using the local supabase GUI. Now I want to push those changes to the remote supabase db . First, I run supabase db diff --file=lang_and_sport_support. generate a new migration with the changes.
But i get an error:
ERROR: type "Gender" already exists (SQLSTATE 42710)                                              
At statement 0: create type "public"."Gender" as enum ('male', 'female', 'other', 'not_specified')

how can I solve this?
I don't want to delete the existing Enum type on the remote DB.
I tried to run supabase db diff then supabase new migration lang_and_sport_support. I copied the difference (which is printed in the console) insinde the new migration file. Then I ran supabase db push. But it results in the same error.
I expect it to migrate my changes to the remote db.
